# How to create a reusable type definition (e.g. in a module)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a type definition to represent the Abstract Syntax Tree returned by the `jsep.parse()` function, for use in my Angular app(s).

The type looks like this:

```
import { ArrayExpression }       from './ast/array-expression';
import { BinaryExpression }      from './ast/binary-expression';
import { CallExpression }        from './ast/call-expression';
import { ConditionalExpression } from './ast/conditional-expression';
import { Identifier }            from './ast/identifier';
import { Literal }               from './ast/literal';
import { LogicalExpression }     from './ast/logical-expression';
import { MemberExpression }      from './ast/member-expression';
import { ThisExpression }        from './ast/this-expression';
import { UnaryExpression }       from './ast/unary-expression';

export type AST = 
    ArrayExpression |
    BinaryExpression |
    CallExpression |
    ConditionalExpression |
    Identifier |
    Literal |
    LogicalExpression |
    MemberExpression |
    ThisExpression |
    UnaryExpression;
```

I'm trying to wrap it into a reusable module.  Unfortunately, when I try to add the type to the module Exports, it complains that I'm using a type as a variable.

If I wanted to capture this type and import it into multiple projects, what is the right way of going about it?

Comment: I've created a ng-module-template you can use to create reusable modules: https://GitHub.com/angular-patterns/ng-module-template

Comment: @pixelbits - I think you misunderstood the question.  I use angular-cli, so creating a module is easy enough.  The problem is, I can't export a type alias that way.  So I'm trying to understand: what is the standard way of re-using the type-alias?

Comment: I don’t think angular/Cali is setup to creat reusable modules

Comment: That is neither here nor there.  The question is not "how to make a module" the question is, how to make a type alias reusable across projects?

Comment: They are synonymous unfortunately. You have to create a reusable module (and it’s not easy) if you want to share it across projects

Comment: export AST=ArrayExpresion|BinaryExpresion|... (not include "type"). In your module import AST from '../YourType.ts' and use let variable:AST

Comment: @Eliseo: If I take out "type" it complains "Cannot find name 'AST'"

Comment: The way to do Type Aliases it's as show https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html.

Comment: The question is not how to create a Type Alias.  If you look at the code above, it declares a type alias correctly.  The question is, what is the right way of exporting that from my module?  As far as I can tell, I have to actually import directly from the `jsep-ast.ts` file.  But is that the RIGHT way?